# is there a subversion web client that I can use

Tags: linux, svn, webclient

I want to install a svn web client on Linux (preferred) or Windows. I need only read-only  capabilities (no commit required) and I want to be able to compare revisions using diff. my svn server is on another machine so the web server needs to access it over http. 
It should also be free...

Do you know any such web client?

Comment: I use websvn now, and it works great. only have one problem and you can see it in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803078/websvn-is-not-ignoring-mime-type

Comment: one more problem with websvn is that it works on apache with mod_php. when installing mod_php on apache I had some difficulties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [websvn (websvnphp.github.io)](https://websvnphp.github.io/) and [viewcvs (viewvc.org)](http://viewvc.org/)

Comment: is websvn allow access over http?

Comment: websvn.info: The domain has been hijacked, editied post.

Answer (score 2):

I believe VisualSVN provides what your looking for: http://www.visualsvn.com/

Comment: That's not a web client, but either a Subversion server or Visual Studio plugin

Comment: it provides a webclient with server when it is installed

Answer (score 2):

Trac does a pretty good job, also Redmine - you can turn all the other features off on both of them.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), but Subversion browsing (with diff) is only part of this project.

*Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects. ...*

*It provides an interface to  Subversion (or other version control systems), an integrated Wiki and convenient reporting facilities.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to spend a little bit of money - try Atlassian Fisheye which is very powerful.

Free for OpenSource-Projects, 10$ for 10 user - more expensive when used for > 10 user

www.atlassian.com

Answer (score 1):

Check out [viewvc](http://viewvc.org/download.html) (it was formerly known as viewcvs).

"ViewVC is a browser interface for CVS and Subversion version control repositories. It generates templatized HTML to present navigable directory, revision, and change log listings. It can display specific versions of files as well as diffs between those versions. Basically, ViewVC provides the bulk of the report-like functionality you expect out of your version control tool, but much more prettily than the average textual command-line program output."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tortoise on Windows.

I do my interacting with SVN in IntelliJ these days.  It's got a terrific interface, especially helpful for merges.

Every client of Subversion is a web client, unless you happen to be logged onto the server where your repository lives.

Comment: by web client I mean html view that can be used with browser.

Comment: In that case your client is your browser, and thus, your whole question is nonsense.

Comment: I don't see why a browser is necessary.  I'm assuming that your users have to be inside your firewall, in which case any client that can see your server is viable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Web-UI for Subversion repositories named as cSvn. Please look at README.md file https://csvn.radix.pro/csvn/trunk/README.md/.

You can download latest 0.1.2 source package from https://ftp.radix.pro/pub/csvn/.

This Web-UI can be installed in wery simple way on your server (like all packages used Autoconf, Automake utility):

```
./configure
make
make install
```

This is very good UI to promotion your opensource work because it support Google Analytics and Donation dialogue and also looks very good on mobile devices (you can see working site https://csvn.radix.pro to make you decision).