# websvn is not ignoring mime type

Tags: svn, mime-types, websvn

I am using websvn to see svn revision comparison. I uncommented
`$config->ignoreSvnMimeTypes();`
 to my config.php, but it seems not to work:

> Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
>   svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workaround was to change the mime type