# SVN web user interface

Tags: svn, svnadmin, websvn

I have recently installed Subversion onto a Linux server (Gentoo).

The question is if there are any web interfaces available for browsing the repositories i.e. get log, diff, blame, etc.

I want to present my work to others via web interface instead of using SSH. It would be great to to show README files written in Markdown.

Comment: Possible old but related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768155/is-there-a-subversion-web-client-that-i-can-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found new Web-UI for Subversion repositories named as cSvn. Please look at README.md file https://csvn.radix.pro/csvn/trunk/README.md/.

You can download latest 0.1.2 source package from https://ftp.radix.pro/pub/csvn/.

This Web-UI can be installed in wery simple way on your server (like all packages used Autoconf, Automake utility):

```
configure
make
make install
```

This is very good UI to promotion your opensource work because it support Google Analytics and Donation dialogue and also looks very good on mobile devices (you can see working site https://csvn.radix.pro to make you decision).

Enjoy.